# How to sequence all numeric elements in R?

Tags: r, vector

I would like to sequence a random vector:

```
<v1 <- apply(combn(1:8,2),2,paste0,collapse="")>
<v2 <- apply(combn(8:1,2),2,paste0,collapse="")>
<v <- c(v1,v2)>
```

Then I got a vector like this:

```
[1] 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 23 24 25 26 27 28 34 35 36 37 38 45 46 47 48 56 57 58 67 68 78
[29] 87 86 85 84 83 82 81 76 75 74 73 72 71 65 64 63 62 61 54 53 52 51 43 42 41 32 31 21
```

However, I want to sequence this vector from small to large number like:

12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 21, 23, 24, 25 .... (11/22/33/44/55/66/77/88 should not be included)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can `sort(v)` or do the whole thing in one line, like this:

```
sort(combn(1:8, 2, \(x) c(paste(x,collapse=""),paste(rev(x), collapse=""))))
```

Output:

```
 [1] "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "21" "23" "24" "25" "26" "27" "28" "31" "32" "34" "35" "36" "37" "38"
[22] "41" "42" "43" "45" "46" "47" "48" "51" "52" "53" "54" "56" "57" "58" "61" "62" "63" "64" "65" "67" "68"
[43] "71" "72" "73" "74" "75" "76" "78" "81" "82" "83" "84" "85" "86" "87"
```

Of course, you can always just do this:

```
(11:88)[(11:88)%%11!=0]
```